# Как конвертировать любой символ в массив, для того чтобы потом рисовать его блоками html

Tags: javascript, html

Стало вот интересно - есть ли какой-то способ превратить любой символ в массив-картинку. Например символ "1" превратить в

```
[ ][ ][1]
[ ][1][1]
[1][ ][1]
[ ][ ][1]
[ ][ ][1]
```

Или же 2 в

```
[1][1][1]
[ ][ ][1]
[ ][1][ ]
[1][ ][ ] 
[1][1][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hаписать черным цветом на белом канвасе и прочитать пиксели.

Comment: Хм, а поподробней можно?

Comment: Это крестики-нолики ? :) вопрос принципиально не ясен, что есть картинка и какая её зависимость от цифры/символа. Разверните вопрос..

Comment: @NewView это не вопрос а ответ